# when Scroll Lock is on superKey doesn't show overview

Tags: keyboard, 22.04

My scroll lock didn't work but I fixed it using the solution that was written [here](http://www.pclinuxos.com/forum/index.php/topic,125690.msg1052201.html?PHPSESSID=2qsv83lve6dgd0ivq14bfcjc30#msg1052201) .When scroll lock is on superkey perform for showing overview doesn't work but when I turn scroll lock off superkey is working properly.

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: there are a number of solutions written "here" [edit] your question with exactly what you did to be clear.

Comment: @24601
I edit that link now you can see the solution.